# How to connect outlet with xib object from code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

What happens when we connect the xib objects with class outlets? How to do such connection from code without wiring them in interface builder?

Comment: http://borkware.com/quickies/one?topic=Bindings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IBOutlets are just instance variables or properties that get set by the nib loading machinery when the nib is loaded at runtime. There's nothing particularly special about them. The trick in setting them up programmatically is finding the object(s) in the nib that you want to connect. If you load the nib using `-[NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:options:]` you get an NSArray back containing all the top level objects in the nib (i.e. the objects at the top of the hierarchy in the Document Outline Inspector in IB). You can iterate through these and their subviews to find the objects you want to hook up IBOutlets. Take a look at the Loading [Nib Files Programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000051i-CH4-SW24) section of the Resource Programming Guide.